# Download from dropbox and upload to user

Tags: php, http

I download the file from Dropbox and give it to the user, but something goes wrong:

[image: screenshot]

This is snippet for MODX so return function:

```
<?php
$token='xxxxx';
  $url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';
  $header_array = array(
     'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
     'Content-Type:',
     'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"' . "/usersUpload/W4zUKvsYbW8dlWi2XtZkdo5kPzoThXq3rBKkTtkNd7o4BPVDrt.png" . '"}'
     );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
  $output_array = array();
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  if ($output === FALSE)
     {
     echo "curl error: " . curl_error($ch);
     }else{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.png');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public'); 


     $return = $response->body;
     }
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Porting the code to a separate php file helped solve the problem.
MODX does something with the returned value.